# MS Graph API for Teams - Webhooks

Tags: microsoft-teams

do you know if there are webhooks for messages in ms teams. I can list all messages and replies via the graph API but I want to have webhook and when there is a new message, I want to receive notification. Is it possible via REST service (I don't want any SDK).

Answer (score 0):

Incoming Webhook and outgoing webhook in apps of MS team